# Number theory, possibility

Tags: number-theory

The number of positive divisors the following number has:

$7^{12}+7^{13}+7^{14}+7^{15}$

Approach for these type of problems.

Is there a pattern in such questions to be recognized.

Comment: $x^{12}+x^{13}+x^{14}+x^{15}=x^{12}(x+1)(x^2+1)$

Comment: Hint : Factor out $7^{12}$ and use the formula for finite geometric series

Comment: @DonaldSplutterwit  $1 + x + x^2 + x^3 = (1+x)(1+x^2)$

Comment: @WillJagy ... silly me ! Thanks for spotting that $\ddot \smile$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can simplify:$$m =7^{12} + 7^{13} + 7^{14} + 7^{15} = 7^{12}(1+7+7^2+7^3)$$
Knowing that: $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(ar^k) = a(\frac{1-r^n}{1-r})$, we can write:$$m =7^{12}(1+7+7^2+7^3) = 7^{12}\frac{7^4 - 1}{6} =  400 * 7^{12} = 2^4 * 5^2 * 7^{12}$$
Now it's simple. We know that the number of divisors of number $n = p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2} p_3^{\alpha_3}...p_k^{\alpha_k}$ equals $(\alpha_1+1)(\alpha_2+1)...(\alpha_k+1)$ we can say that number of divisors of our number equals $$\tau(m) = 5 * 3 * 13 = 195$$
General idea in this types of problems is to somehow factorize the number $m$ or to represent it as some kind of a product and then easily work it out. Notice that we could have solved this using $(1 + x + x^2 + x^3) = (x + 1)(x^2+ 1)$, but that's sometimes difficult to see.